# Use PHP to highlight cells in table depending on entry to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to display a timetable of sorts on my webpage. I need to use PHP to highlight table cells depending on whether they have an entry to the database for todays date. I currently have a table with rooms across the top and times down the side as below:

```
echo "<table border-1>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>B-12</th>
        <th>G.05</th>
        <th>G.06</th>
        <th>1.04</th>
        <th>1.05</th>
        <th>1.06</th>
        <th>2.04</th>
        <th>2.05</th>
        <th>2.06</th>
        <th>3.04</th>
        <th>3.05</th>
        <th>3.06</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>9.00</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>9.30</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10.00</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10.30</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>";
```

I need to read entries to my database and highlight the corresponding cell, in the correct room column and in the correct time row, based on the entry date,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDYMP.jpg)

Is there a way to do this in PHP? Am I going about this all wrong? I am new to PHP so am not entirely sure what is the best method to achieve what I need.

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this but have found none that answer my question. If anyone has any idea or could advise me on the best method I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you currently using PHP to generate this table? If so please edit your question to add that PHP code. It should be fairly easy to modify it to do what you're trying to do. If not, then this question is really too broad.

Comment: Could you please really define what you mean by 'correct room column and in the correct time row'. It is not clear what should be highlighted and when

Comment: @Bizmate Sorry this is a bit vague. I have added an image to show what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still a bit confused if you question is more about how to interact with mysql or how to display occupancy/availability in each room.

I assume it is the latter. I also assume you know how to get your data from mysql and you just need a way on how to display the occupancy.

```
<?php

$roomsAvailability = [
    '1' => ['9:30', '10:30'],
    '2' => ['10:00'],
    '3' => ['9:00', '11:00'],
];

$times = ['8:30', '9:00','9:30', '10:00', '10:30',  '11:00'];

?>
<style>
table, th, td {
    margin:5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.available {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>g1</th><th>g2</th><th>g3</th></tr>
<?php

foreach($times as $time)
{?>
    <tr>
    <?php
        echo "<td>$time</td>";
        foreach($roomsAvailability as $roomNumber => $roomAvailability)
        {
            if(in_array($time , $roomAvailability))
            {
                echo "<td class='available'>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td class='notAvailable'>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
<?php
}

?>
</table>
```

In the script above you can see how i represent the availability in a variable for the rooms (lets assume you get this array from the database). Also the times (for instance times of business/slots) are also in the db.

In general in a db you would have relations and more elaborate things that I have skipped from the answer.

The script displays a table similar to the one you added in your question with cells where the room is allocated marked with a lightblue background.

You can copy and run it on  [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) to see the output.

Please let me know if it is what you were looking for

Comment: Yes, as a starting point this is perfect. I just was not sure of the best method to display the bookings. This is so helpful. Thank you so much!